# R-For Loop implementation of user defined function

Tags: r, for-loop, iteration

I am pretty new to R and self taught. I have background in other languages, and I think that is what is tripping me up right now. 
I doing statistical analysis in R and wrote the function zoneFinder that takes input (distNum) and outputs (zoneNum). zoneFinder works fine when I call it in RStudio and manually input both valid and invalid outputs, so I do not think that's my issue.

-Is a data frame the correct structure to store the output? if not, what is?

-I have tried using nrows(ds) for the range through which the for loop iterates, but that wasn't working (though I guess neither is manually inputting the data range)

-is this the correct structure for a for loop in R? I am having trouble getting to the [row][distNum] element, and I don't know how to access that directly.

```
zoneNums <- data.frame()
#creates a data structure to store function output

#for loop to iterate through row, send the distNum value for that row, and return zoneID 
for (row in 1 : nrow(ds) ){

#trying to obtain the value stored at ds[current rownumber, variable distNum]
 distSubmit <- as.numeric(ds[row, "distNum"])

#storing the result from the function as zoneID
 zoneID <- zoneFinder(distSubmit)

#adding the new value of zoneID into the premade data structure zoneNums
 zoneNums<- c(zoneID)
 #zoneNums[row,ds$zoneNum] <- zoneID
}
```

I've tried every google resource I can and the people in my life who know a little about R to no avail. Assistance would be very very welcome! I can answer any follow up questions as well. I'm consciously not including my output right now because it's super long, and is the loop iterating through the entire data set for each iteration. Thanks!

Comment: When your loop is `for (row in ...)` I'd expect you to use `row` inside the loop more than just to `cat("row: ", row)`. You don't use it again, so nothing else in your loop changes between iterations.

Comment: Like, in your comment you have `ds[current rownumber, variable distNum]`, which is almost correct syntax. I would expect the code to be `ds[row, "distNum"]`... but `ds$distNum` doesn't use `row` at all.

Comment: @GregorThomas great feedback thank you. I'll try that syntax now!

Comment: Is `ds[row, "distNum"]` just a single number (perhaps after converted with `as.numeric()`, or is it a *vector* of such things?

Comment: @AaronMontgomery ds[row,"distNum"] is ideally returning the value that is contained in my data set ds at in row (row) for "distNum" as I currently have planned and envisioned. my background for programming is more c++ and java and I'm afraid I'm approaching it from those standpoints and not from an R mindframe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally it is better to use the apply family of functions rather than looping structures.  So something like this using sapply:

```
distSubmit <- as.numeric(ds$distNum) #is the input vector for sapply

zoneNums <- sapply(distSubmit, zoneFinder)
```

will return a vector (`zoneNums`) of the return values from `zoneFinder` for each element of the `distSubmit` vector.

Note when returning non-atomic types, use `lapply` instead which returns a list of outputs.

Comment: the actual solution to manipulate the correct piece of data was to use lapply(ds$distNum, zoneFinder) so thank you for getting me on the right track!